# Is homeopathic treatment proper for cats?

Tags: cats, medicines

I have no idea about homeopathy. However, I have seen many of my relatives and neighbors administering homeopathic medicine to their sick cat. I am wondering if this approach is right or wrong.

Comment: `I have no idea about homeopathy` don't worry: practitioners of "homeopathy" have no idea either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth remembering homeopathy in the Indian context is a *little* strange, occasionally pulling in aspects of various native medicine, and well, some homespun oddness.

*Any* alternative medical system, without a solid grounding in the species in question and used opposed to, rather in conjunction with modern veterinary science is a wee bit suspect to me. I wouldn't bet the life of my best friend on it

Practically speaking for anything that matters, though, homeopathy is basically completely useless. Ars Technica has (well many articles but this one specifically) [an article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2007/09/the-pseudoscience-behind-homeopathy/) which I'll be drawing on for my answer. It's 7 pages - and that's cause this is a complex topic, even for a pop science website and it basically points out flaws in methodology in homeopathy believers.

The idea behind homeopathy is you can dilute some substance with the same effect as the illness in water, to the point where it's undetectable, and that somehow helps the body heal itself.

So... you're basically giving your cat water. Which is *fine*, assuming the cat needs a drink.  They claim it works cause water has memory. The water you drink has been through... well, dinosaurs, maybe Romans, Greeks. It might have floated through space as a comet. This wouldn't really work unless water has *selective* memory, or somehow the most recent thing done to it matters somehow. Of course, none of this is scientifically provable (the article I linked talks about bad science there).

I'd consider it pseudoscience, and it's unlikely to help outside making the owner feel like they're doing something.

Comment: Wait... water makes me Strong Like A T-Rex!!!!!!! Sorry, could not quiet resist here! :) On a more serious note: Homeopathy as ADDITIONAL treatment for your cat may have a benefit IF you believe in it because apparently, pets can pick up when YOU feel THEY should feel better, so they sometimes do. Minds are weird things...

Comment: Interestingly the person who gave me my cat as a baby, said that the cat is having some stomach upset, and the person gave me the homeopathic medicines that were being given to the cat.